# Передать сигнал и слот QT как параметр

Tags: c++, qt, классы, указатели, функциональное-программирование

Есть библиотека которая общается с устройством либо через usb, либо через ethernet, либо еще через что то. И хотелось бы что бы передать в конструктор библиотеки только слот и сигнал для отправки и приема сообщения.

```
class Lib : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Lib (QObject obj, iDontKnow slotSendData, iDontKnow2 signalRxDataReady, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    // some code
signals:
    // Необходимо связать с slotSendData.
    void sendData(QByteArray msg);
public slots:
    // Необходимо связать с signalRxDataReady.
    virtual void rxMsg(QByteArray msg) = 0;
}

class Eth : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // some code
public slots:
    void sendData(QByteArray msg);
signals:
    virtual void rxDataReady(QByteArray msg) = 0;
}

class Usb : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // some code
public slots:
    void sendData(QByteArray msg);
signals:
    virtual void rxDataReady(QByteArray msg) = 0;
}

int main() {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Eth e; Usb u;
    Lib l(&e, &Eth::sendData, &Eth::rxDataReady);
}
```

Comment: насколько я знаю, Qt обращается к слотам как к `const char*`

Comment: и похоже, что на [Qt форуме](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8392-How-to-declare-SLOT-as-a-parameter-to-member-function) есть ответ на Ваш вопрос